# Break out some controllers in an area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I have three controllers in an area in my application that I want to break out from the rest of the area. For instance I would like a url like `/Area/Approve/Timesheet/Action` and then be able to still have `/Area/Timesheet/Action` that both have completely different functionality (one approves the time sheet as a supervisor, the other fills out the time sheet as an employee). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible, as long as you have the right routes set up. Remember that even though the default MVC Area template shows one particular route pattern, in the end, all the routes go into the same global routing table, so as long as you set the right URL patterns, you should be good to go.

If you're having trouble with any particular set of routes, please specify what you have and what isn't working.